# How to view result of promise without resuming code execution while debugging?

Tags: javascript, promise, visual-studio-debugging

Scenario:

I have new object, I want to play with it live while it's in certain state.

To do that I put debugger where I wanted to investigate it.

This object happens to functions that return promises.

I call that function in console. `user.getViews();`

I get `Promise.unresolve...` back

How do I get this promise to work, as in return value. If I had `.then` that also just return another promise, `then` only executes if I resume paused environment, which happened due to debugger command.

I tried putting `await` which didn't work.

Comment: Can we see your code in full?

Comment: It'd be simple nodejs controller. My question is clear though... if you have code paused due to breakpoint, how can you run and view result of promise in console without resuming code.

Comment: if i write in console `user.name` I'll get value. I do anything synchronous it will work.  But asynchronous is done in event loop which is stopped due to breakpoint. So how do you play with async code without resuming code execution.

Comment: @Muhammad Umer, If your code was not really called after the breakpoint was hit, it was hard for you to view the real result of the next steps. Maybe "Set Next Statement" is what you want to get: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: Are you debugging with `--inspect`? You can just go to the promise and type the promise's name in the code and it'll show you the resolution value for it.

Comment: Oh wait, you're debugging from visual studio - no idea it's up to them there. Maybe evaluate `util.inspect(yourPromise)`.

Comment: no i mean i want to test a function by calling it in console. but it returns a promise, but i want to see the value of resolved promise